# Django's get_initial() method not working as desired

Tags: django

I am using django's generic CreateView to build a comment system for my site. A user is allowed to do comment for a movie. Here is my Comment model-

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return "comment by {} on {}".format(self.user.first_name, self.movie)
```

Here is the CreateView i am using-

```
class AddComment(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        #for providing initial values to the form
        initial['user'] = self.request.user.id
        initial['movie'] = self.kwargs['movie_id']
        return initial

    def get_success_url(self):
        movie_id = self.kwargs['movie_id']
        return reverse('detail', kwargs={'pk':movie_id})

    def render_to_response(self, context=None, **response_kwargs):
        movie_id = self.kwargs['movie_id']
        return redirect(to = reverse('detail', kwargs={'pk':movie_id}))
```

Here is the commentform -

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, queryset=get_user_model().objects.all())
    movie = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, queryset=Movie.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('user','movie', 'body')
```

I am trying to associate a comment to a user and a movie. I thus used get_initial() method to fill the form with initial data because user and movie were not present in the posted data. But somehow always form.is_valid() turns out to be false. I don't know where i went wrong. Please Help.

If it helps i tried to debug my program by printing out the value of kwargs that were being used to instantiate the form object by overriding the get_form_kwargs function-

```
{
'initial': {'user': 1, 'movie': 2}, 'prefix': None, 
'data': <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['wFmkOMLAcIszMc17GsBsqPhyaZnJEXb0TRNteKd9sgjYKEF3jvqwsQ3Noik3DHq6'], 'body': ['best movie ever\r\n'], 'user': [''], 'movie': ['']}>, 'files': <MultiValueDict: {}>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, user and movie are Foreign key fields, so that they expect to receive object of related models as initials. You are trying  to use pk(int) instead of these objects.
It should be like following:

```py
 def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        #for providing initial values to the form
        initial['user'] = self.request.user 
        initial['movie'] = Movie.objects.get(pk=movie_id)
        return initial.copy()
```

Comment: I did as you told but still no comment is being added. Please elaborate a bit

Comment: I do not get any error messages. Each time a type a comment, only the render_to_response function runs. I know that this function runs because the form is invalid in some sense. Since i have given the same url in render_to_response function, the page gets redirected to the movie detail page without any error being displayed. But the comment does not get stored at the backend.